# Can't cache the value from _GET with the _POST submission

Tags: php

I tried to search for similar questions but couldn't find the answer.
This is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo $id;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="update_post.php">
    <input type="text" name="post_title" value="<?php echo $post['post_title']; ?>"></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Post">
</form>
```

URL: localhost/.../update_post.php?id=3

All it does is check the URL for the ?id= value if its set. If yes, then assign that to variable $id and then when the post form is submitted echo that variable.. I got this error always:

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in
>   ...update_post.php on line 9

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: `action="update_post.php"` has no __id__.

Comment: Start with question - why do I think that `$id` is defined?

Comment: @u_mulder What do you mean? It's submitting to itself. It is defined because I got it via _GET and cached it into a variable.

Comment: Do you understand that form submits to `update_post.php` and not to `update_post.php?id=3`? Do you?

Comment: I'm grateful to you @u_mulder yes, I can see my problem now. Thank you very much for your help :)